# Custom web app login page using ADAL.net to validate Azure AD credentials

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, owin, adal

In a web application custom login page validating the Active directory username and password. I know it may lower application security by having in my own custom login page. May i know how do get the access token by verifying username and password in the application custom login page.

Looks like the following but in more detail i want...Authenticating to Azure AD using a username & password in ADAL.net:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

Something like this:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
 var userCredential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
 var token = authContext.AcquireToken(ResourceUrl, ClientId, userCredential);
```

Comment: I would recommend not making a custom login page for a few reasons. Firstly, it lowers your security by having your app handle passwords unnecessarily. Secondly, certain users will be unable to log in using your login page. This includes users with MFA. Do you want to disable MFA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebForms authentication against Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991205/webforms-authentication-against-azure-ad)

Comment: Juunas - I agree it may lower the security, still would like to match up login template to other pages. MFA- is that mean Multi factor authentication you are referring to?May not be needed this one. Again this may reflect on lower security. That is fine.

Comment: Astaykov - It is not a duplicate question from your referring url...which is prompting for Azure AD login but my requirement is not to redirect to Azure AD. Application itself should validate credentials against Azure AD and get the access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following links are more useful:

Authenticating to Azure AD using a username & password in ADAL.net: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-headless

This one is in more detail, but the drawback is, having the outdated screenshots:
https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/01/29/authenticating-to-azure-ad-non-interactively/

Here is the new UI information: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-registrations-training-guide

In short: The two Azure apps to be created on the server as per the first link: one is as Client and other one is as Service(Resource). The only thing the above links did not mention about is setting the Client app's (at AD Azure settings) "default client type" to Yes (under Authentication).  The following code replaces the LDAP.

The following method to be called in ApplicationUserManager.

```
public override async Task<bool> CheckPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => IsAuthenticated(user.UserName, password));
    }


private bool IsAuthenticated(string username, string pwd)
    {            
        bool authenticated = false;
        try
        {
            //token cache not to set, that is the reason sending the null value
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-ID}/oauth2/token", true, null);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;

            var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, pwd);
            authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://tenantname.onmicrosoft.com/ServiceAppId", "ClientAppId", credential).Result;

           authenticated = true;
        }           
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;               
            //not authenticated due to some other exception 
        }
        return authenticated;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link 3 is broken

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the resource owner password credential grant. There is more information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc . Have in mind that it lowers your security.

Comment: Looks like it is taking to good direction, but could not find the sample web app using ROPC. console application is not helpful fully.